# Why does the value in event.target not equal event.target.value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, dom-events

I am learning react, and noticed when changing an input of type number and outputting `event.target` I see a different value then that when I output `event.target.value`.
I am wondering why this is?

Some sample code to show what I am talking about:

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <input type="number" 
      value={this.props.weight}
      onChange={(event) => this.props.onWeightChange(event, this.props.index)}
      step="0.1" />
    );
  }
}
class Parent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    text: 'Goals', 
    weight: 1
  }
  handleStatWeightChange = (event, index) => {
    console.log(event.target)  
    console.log(event.target.value)
  }
  render() { 
    return (
      <div>
        <Child weight={this.state.weight} onWeightChange={this.handleStatWeightChange}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
 }


React.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

When changing the input value (from 1.1 from 1) I see the following output in the console:

```
"<input type='number' value='1' step='0.1' data-reactid='.0.0'>"
"1.1"
```

why is the value in `event.target` still 1?

Comment: I should maybe add, I realize the handleStatWeightChange is not actually handing the change at the moment.

Comment: Because you hard coded value to 1 in input element

Comment: Then why does event.target.value updated? Shouldnt event.target.value be pulling that value attribute I can see in the first output line?

Also if I edit the handler to actually update the state to the new value, event.target never changes (will always show value='1') whereas event.target.value will output the actual current value.

Comment: Can you also share your Child component code

Comment: All the code is shared. class Child is the child component.

Comment: Here it is in codepen if that helps. https://codepen.io/str8wavedave/pen/GXVomW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting event.target.value to weight in handleStatWeightChange event handler function

Try with below change it would work

```
handleStatWeightChange = (event, index) => {
    this.setState({
      weight: event.target.value
    })
    console.log(event.target)  
    console.log(event.target.value)
  }
```

Comment: I realize I wasnt actually handling the change. This doesnt actually answer my question. (but it does help illustrate it more)

if with the above code I input 4, I will see 

"<input type='number' value='1' step='0.1' data-reactid='.0.0'>"
for the console.log(event.target). And
"4" for the console.log(event.target.value)

I dont understand why in event.target it still says value=1 when event.target.value =4. 

This isnt really a blocker or anything for me just something I am trying to understand.

Comment: Got it. event.target renders only input element with the initial value no matter what you input in the field. For eg if you initialize weight to 10 then event.target will show value as 10